# Examples of kinetic modeling with optimization techniques in Python

Tags: optimization, python, computational-chemistry

We are looking for studies or tools that implemented kinetic modeling with parameter estimation differential evolution or similar optimization techniques in Python.

We are trying to understand what already exists in this area.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some results from your preliminary research that exemplify the kind of publications you are looking for. For example, modulo the Python aspect, is the following the kind of paper you are trying to locate? Sebastian Matera, William F. Schneider, Andreas Heyden, and Aditya Savara, "Progress in Accurate Chemical Kinetic Modeling, Simulations, and Parameter Estimation for Heterogeneous Catalysis", *ACS Catal.* 2019, 9, 8, 6624–6647. Obviously, relevant work will utilize a variety of programming languages. What is the significance of focusing on Python? Please clarify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first comment was already helpful, thanks! We refined the question a bit, hopefully is clearer now.